Android: Running detekt with type resolution on whole code base
Do I understand correctly I need to run 3 Gradle tasks to have covered the whole project (production code, unit tests, android tests) by detekt with type resolution?
For build variant AB it would be detektAP, detektABUnitTest, detektABAndroidTest.
As far as I understand the configuration without the compiler plugin, it would mean 3 builds, right?
My post is based on
https://youtu.be/6EQd_SDR6n0?si=rXcI0V31Ybm9xiVg&t=906 Runs another compilation Internally to resolve types
and https://detekt.dev/docs/gettingstarted/gradle
My expectation is to run one Gradle task to check the whole project (with type resolution).
